# How i can use FullText such as Like

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Sorry for my english...

Hi,
i have a database with 8.000.000 records.
My problem is that I have to find the record that exactly matches the search word.

For example if i search "Venezia" I just want the record containing the exact word "venezia".

With like it's ok (but slow 5.0176 sec):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `my_table` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE  'venezia'

#id #name
1 Venezia
5 Venezia
20 Venezia
....
```

Witch match against is fast (0.0012 sec) but incorrect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `my_table` 
WHERE 
MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"venezia"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

#id #name
1 Venezia        (ok)
7 Venezia Lido   (no)
21 Hotel Venezia (no)
...
```

I would only record with name value "Venezia".

thank you

Comment: Full text search will check every word in the specified column, this is what it is meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

you can think of implementing solr search or elastic search in your project to speed up your search which are search engines.
Look at this link for further information http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly equial sign to fetch exact record.

```
SELECT *  FROM  `my_table`  WHERE  `name` = 'venezia'
```

Comment: You can also specify index for that column so it will search faster.